# XML - make element above of a element?

Tags: android, xml

I want to make text view above of list view like this :
[image]

This is my XML script :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
     >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvVouchers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am confusing for making textview above of list view...

Comment: does each list row has the textview ??

Comment: The textview is above of listview. If user scroll listview, textview position isn't changed.

Comment: So you  want to keep the text view on the top of list view without scrolling or do you want to scroll the text view  with  list view ?

Comment: I have mentioned two scenarios in my comment , 01. keep the text view on the top of list as it is      02. scroll the text view with list view . What is it ? 01 or 02 ?

Comment: I hope you answer my question than commenting...

Comment: No, it doesn't work. You can test below codes by yourself...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74098/discussion-between-davidjhons-and-andika-kurniawan).

Comment: Try a relative layout and toy with the values. If you take a default relative layout the views overlap in the top left corner. I suppose you can make them do that on the right side also if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.8" >
</ListView>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.2">

</TextView>
```

But you have to set the text with \n  after each character as follows,

```
textView.setText("a" + "\n" + "b" + "\n" +"c" + "\n" +"d" + "\n" );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
     >
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvVouchers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```